# Toggle showing and hiding components in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been struggling to show/hide components in ReactJs for a couple of days. I am trying to show the ("Write(blocks)" - which needs to be hidden from view by default) and shown when the "edit" links are clicked (while toggling hide / show for the "Read" blocks) and hide them when either the "save" or "cancel" buttons are clicked, I will be taking care of the save function later. For now I am just trying to show / hide the component based on this.

Below is my code:

```
class ProfileSettings extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ProfileSettings">

        <SettingsBlock className="Names" label="Name" link="name">
          <p className="readOnlySettingField ReadNames">Hilal Agil<a href="#">Edit</a></p>

          <div className="WriteNames">
            <SubBlock label="First Name" placeholder="First Name" />
            <SubBlock label="Middle Name" placeholder="Middle Name" />
            <SubBlock label="Last Name" placeholder="Last Name" />
            <p className="notice"><strong>Please note:</strong> You wont be able to change your name within the next 30 days. 
            Make sure not to add any unusual capitalization, punctuation, characters or random words.</p>
            <button className="button small fill primary">Save Changes</button>
            <button className="button small default">Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </SettingsBlock>

        <SettingsBlock label="Username" link="username">

          <p className="readOnlySettingField ReadUsername">www.squelo.com/hilarl<a href="#">Edit</a></p>

          <div className="WriteUsername">
            <p className="notice url">squelo.com/hilarl</p>
            <Input placeholder="Username" classes="col-md-7" />
            <p className="notice"><strong>Please note:</strong> Your username can only be changed once and should include your authentic name.</p>
            <button className="button small fill primary">Save Changes</button>
            <button className="button small default">Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </SettingsBlock>

        <SettingsBlock label="Email" link="email">
          <p className="readOnlySettingField ReadEmail">hilal@gmail.com<a href="#">Edit</a></p>

          <div className="WriteEmail">
            <Input placeholder="Email" classes="col-md-9" />
            <p className="notice"><strong>Please note:</strong> Your username can only be changed once and should include your authentic name.</p>
            <button className="button small fill primary">Save Changes</button>
            <button className="button small default">Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </SettingsBlock>

        <SettingsBlock className="Password" label="Password" link="password">
          <p className="readOnlySettingField ReadPassword">Password last changed over a year ago<a href="#">Edit</a></p>

          <div className="WritePassword">
            <SubBlock label="Current" placeholder="Current" />
            <SubBlock label="New" placeholder="New" />
            <SubBlock label="Re-type new" placeholder="Re-type new" />
            <p className="notice"><a href="#">Forgot password?</a></p>
            <button className="button small fill primary">Save Changes</button>
            <button className="button small default">Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </SettingsBlock>
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

Would be great if somebody could give an example for how to achieve this in this situation. I have been wasting a lot of time figuring this out myself and this is the first time I am using ReactJs in a project. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the pattern I would use.

```
    render() {
        var hideWriteBlock = (show hide logic);
        var hideReadBlock = (show hide logic);
        return (
            <div className="ProfileSettings">

                <SettingsBlock className="Names" label="Name" link="name" hide={hideWriteBlock}>
```

In the settings component;

```
    render() {
        if (this.props.hide) return null;
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

I use hide so that I don't have to write if (!this.props.show) return null;.

Comment: Are there cases where using CSS to hide the component's content (like I did before trying React), rather than returning null content, is advantageous?

Comment: @MikeC I used to use css visible. Had an experience where render times were dragging. Solved the issue by using this pattern instead.