# How to have a React spinner component that I can call up from anywhere?

Tags: reactjs

My goal is to have a spinner component that I can pop up anywhere I want, while some activity is being carried out.

For example, let's say I have this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className={this.props.className}
          noValidate>
      {React.Children.map(this.props.children, this.renderChild)}
    </form>
  )
},
```

This is my `handleSubmit` method, but it doesn't work properly:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  React.render(<SmartSpinner />, React.findDOMNode(this));
},
```

The screen goes black and I get some nasty warnings. The `SmartSpinner` will cover the entire web page, so it doesn't really matter where it's positioned (it's `position: fixed`), but I do need to call it up programmatically. In other words, I don't want to have to do this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className={this.props.className}
            noValidate>
        {React.Children.map(this.props.children, this.renderChild)}
      </form>
      {this.state.busy ? <SmartSpinner /> : ""}
    </div>
  )
}
```

So what's a good way to do a spinner or modal or some other temporary overlay in the current page/component?

Comment: Look here; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32359542/toggle-showing-and-hiding-components-in-reactjs/32361229#32361229

Answer (score 0):

Place the spinner component in a top-level component. Then use PubSub or another event system to trigger the spinner from anywhere, f.ex:

```
var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { spinning: false }
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.spinnerToken = PubSub.subscribe('spinner', function(e) {
      this.setState({ spinning: !!e.start })
    }.bind(this))
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    PubSub.unsubscribe(this.spinnerToken)
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MainComponent />
        <Spinner style={{ display: this.state.spinning ? 'block' : 'none' }}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```

Now you can just call `PubSub.publish('spinner', { start: true })` from anywhere ( I used https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS here).

Comment: I can't use `display: block/none` to show/hide it, because even if it's set to `display: none`, the spinner's `componentDidMount()` will still fire off, and I have a 2-second delay in that method before it actually shows the spinner. In other words, when the spinner is finally set to `display: block`, it will show up immediately.

Comment: I don’t understand that comment, but having a 2secs delay in the componentDidMount method sounds like a really bad idea. What are you trying to do?

Comment: If you don’t want to use display for toggling, try something like `{this.state.spinning ? <Spinner /> : null}` instead

Comment: It's not a bad idea. The problem with most spinners is that they pop up immediately upon a user action (such as clicking submit). I'm creating a spinner component that will wait 2 seconds (or 1.5 if I feel 2 is too long) before showing up, so that every time a user does some sort of interaction, they don't see a spinner pop up for a few hundred milliseconds. It comes down to making a better user experience.