# React not finding events

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am implementing a very simple React login page. I have started with the following component, Account.

```
var Account = React.createClass({

getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        showSignUp: false,
        showLogin: true
    }
},

update: function(data) {
    this.setState(data);
},

render: function() {
    if(this.state.showSignUp) {
        return <SignUp/>
    }
    else {
        return <Login update={this.update}/>
    }
}

});
```

As expected, the Login component is displayed and renders the following:

```
return (
        <div>
            <p><input type="text" placeholder={Language.languagePack.account.username} onChange={this.usernameChange}/></p>
            <p><input type="password" placeholder={Language.languagePack.account.password} onChange={this.passwordChange}/></p>
            <p><a onClick={this.performLogin}>{Language.languagePack.account.login}</a></p>
            <p><a onClick={this.handleSignUp}>{Language.languagePack.account.signUp}</a></p>
            <p>{failedMessage}</p>
        </div>
    )
```

This all works fine. The application is picking up on the changes via the onChange hook. If the user clicks "Sign Up" though, then the following code is called:

```
handleSignUp: function() {
    this.props.update({showSignUp: true, showLogin: false})
},
```

Which calls the update method in the Account class, which updates the state and causes a re-render. This is what causes it to switch to the SignUp component.

```
return (
        <div id="signUp">
            <p><input type="text" placeholder={Language.languagePack.account.username} onChange={this.usernameChange} /></p>
            <p><input type="password" placeholder={Language.languagePack.account.password} onChange={this.passwordChange} /></p>
            <p><input type="email" placeholder={Language.languagePack.account.email} onChange={this.emailChange} /></p>
            <p><a onClick={this.handleSignUp}>{Language.languagePack.account.signUp}</a></p>
        </div>
    )
```

And for some reason, none of the events are firing on this. onChange or onClick doesn't seem to be registered. I think this is related to my implementation of switching components based on a state change that renders different components. My question is, why is this happening and what part of React have I misunderstood to make this happen?

**Full Classes**

**Login Component**

```
var Login = React.createClass({

getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        username: '',
        password: '',
        failed: false
    }
},

usernameChange: function(event) {
    this.setState({
        username: event.target.value,
        failed: false
    });
},

passwordChange: function(event) {
    this.setState({
        password: event.target.value,
        failed: false
    });
},

performLogin: function() {
    var username = this.state.username;
    var password = this.state.password;

    console.log("Attempting login with username " + username + " and password " + password);

    var _this = this;

    Api.login(username, password, function(response) {
        _this.props.update({user: response, loggedIn: true});
    },
    function(response) {
        _this.setState({failed: true});
    })
},

handleSignUp: function() {
    this.props.update({showSignUp: true, showLogin: false})
},

render: function() {
    var failedMessage = null;

    if(this.state.failed) {
        failedMessage = <div className="failed-auth">{Language.languagePack.account.invalidCredentials}</div>;
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <p><input type="text" placeholder={Language.languagePack.account.username} onChange={this.usernameChange}/></p>
            <p><input type="password" placeholder={Language.languagePack.account.password} onChange={this.passwordChange}/></p>
            <p><a onClick={this.performLogin}>{Language.languagePack.account.login}</a></p>
            <p><a onClick={this.handleSignUp}>{Language.languagePack.account.signUp}</a></p>
            <p>{failedMessage}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
});
```

**Signup Component**

```
var SignUp = React.createClass({

getInitialState : function() {
    return {
        username: '',
        password: '',
        email: ''
    }
},

usernameChange: function(event) {
    this.setState({
        username: event.target.value
    });
},

passwordChange: function(event) {
    this.setState({
        password: event.target.value
    });
},

emailChange: function(event) {
    this.setState({
        email: event.target.value
    });
},

handleSignUp : function() {
    var username = this.state.username;
    var password = this.state.password;
    var email = this.state.email;

    console.log("Signing up with username=" + username + " and password=" + password + "and email=" + email);
},

handleLogin : function() {
    console.log("Fired!");
},

render: function () {
    return (
        <div id="signUp">
            <p><input type="text" placeholder={Language.languagePack.account.username} onChange={this.usernameChange} /></p>
            <p><input type="password" placeholder={Language.languagePack.account.password} onChange={this.passwordChange} /></p>
            <p><input type="email" placeholder={Language.languagePack.account.email} onChange={this.emailChange} /></p>
            <p><a onClick={this.handleSignUp}>{Language.languagePack.account.signUp}</a></p>
        </div>
    )
}
});
```

Comment: Can you switch back to the login after switching to sign up?
If you change username in sign up, doesn't it change when you revert again to login?

Comment: No, no event is fired and nothing changes anywhere. I can't switch back because i can't attach an event to anything in the sign up view.

Comment: What if you change the initial state of Account, to show the sign up form first instead? Still no events?

Comment: Events work perfectly if it is the first one to show. I believe it is something to do with the rerendering process not binding events?

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ that reproduces the issue? I can't see anything obvious wrong and you didn't post the code that actually renders the components.

Comment: I'm implementing a codepen right now, but when I attempt to create a small example that attempts to illustrate this, it just seems to work perfectly. I can update with the Render method. Actually, I did post the code that renders the components, along with the full components.

Comment: Oh at the very top, right. Well, the fact that you are unable to reproduce could imply that the issue us somewhere else.

Comment: Updated the version of react to 14 and it's working perfectly. Strange but solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does work; However, I did remove references to `language.LanguagePack`, since that's not defined in the code you provided.  If you have a javascript error, it will prevent code from running.

https://jsfiddle.net/tqz3skcr/2/

```
var SignUp = React.createClass({

getInitialState : function() {
    return {
        username: '',
        password: '',
        email: ''
    }
},

usernameChange: function(event) {
    console.log('username Changed');
    this.setState({
        username: event.target.value
    });
},

passwordChange: function(event) {
    console.log('password Changed');
    this.setState({
        password: event.target.value
    });
},

emailChange: function(event) {
    console.log('email changed');
    this.setState({
        email: event.target.value
    });
},

handleSignUp : function() {
    var username = this.state.username;
    var password = this.state.password;
    var email = this.state.email;

    console.log("Signing up with username=" + username + " and password=" + password + "and email=" + email);
},

handleLogin : function() {
    console.log("Fired!");
},

render: function () {
    return (
        <div id="signUp">
            <p><input type="text" onChange={this.usernameChange} /></p>
            <p><input type="password" onChange={this.passwordChange} /></p>
            <p><input type="email" onChange={this.emailChange} /></p>
            <p><a onClick={this.handleSignUp}></a></p>
        </div>
    )
}
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <SignUp />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: Solved this in a vey similar way to you. Stripped out all of the crap and went back to first principles. Well done. +150!

Answer (score -1):

I don't see anything obvious but you could try this pattern to show/hide the components. [Toggle showing and hiding components in ReactJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32359542/toggle-showing-and-hiding-components-in-reactjs/32361229#32361229).

Comment: Tried that and observed the same behaviour. First component had events; second did not.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, make your life easier and don't use indicators like:

```
{
    showSignUp: true,
    showLogin: false
}
```

something like this would be much simpler and would produce less errors:

```
{
    formToShow: "signUpForm" // or "loginForm" 
}
```

I would say, if you start coding in this way the issue will resolve by "clean code magic" ))